# Global Action partly cutting off

Tags: aura, global-actions

It's a global action a calling an Aura component which is holding a flow. Yes the user can hit the maximize button but they shouldn't have to. I added <ui:scrollerWrapper hoping it would fix it, it doesn't you can scroll to the 'bottom' and the next button is hidden if there's just a bit too much content.

It's silly to scroll to the bottom of something and not see the content.

My current solution which i'm not a fan of is hosting this aura component in another component that's running on version 39 and using dom manipulation to maximize the screen.

I'm familiar with LWCs is something like this possible in an LWC? I didn't use one because the directions for globalaction-->flow (google-fu search) [specify aura.](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/how-to-invoke-a-flow-from-a-global-action)

[image]

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <ui:scrollerWrapper class="scrollerSize">
        <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"  onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />
    </ui:scrollerWrapper>  
</aura:component>



    ({
    init : function (component) {
        // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
        // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow’s Unique Name.
        flow.startFlow("Salesforce_Request");
    },
    
    handleStatusChange : function (component, event) {  
        console.log(event.getParam("status"));
        if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
            var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
            dismissActionPanel.fire();
        }        
}
})
```